# Flask SqlAlcheny TypeError: 'Fermentables' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy

No *model* `FermentableTypes`:

```
class FermentableTypes(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "fermentable_types"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    desc = db.Column(db.String(255))
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

No *model* `FermentableProducers`:

```
class FermentableProducers(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "fermentable_producers"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    desc = db.Column(db.String(255))
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

No *model* `Fermentables`:

```
class Fermentables(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "fermentables"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50))
    desc = db.Column(db.String(255))
    ppg = db.Column(db.Integer)
    color = db.Column(db.Integer)
    fermentable_types_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('fermentable_types.id'))
    fermentable_types = db.relationship('FermentableTypes', backref=db.backref('fermentables', lazy='dynamic'))
    fermentable_producers_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('fermentable_producers.id'))
    fermentable_producers = db.relationship('FermentableProducers', backref=db.backref('fermentables', lazy='dynamic'))
```

---

Popular o banco de dados:

```
db.session.add_all((
    FermentableProducers(name='Agrária'),
    FermentableProducers(name='Castle Malting')))
db.session.commit()
db.session.add_all((
    FermentableTypes(name='Malte de cevada'),
    FermentableTypes(name='Malte de trigo'),
    FermentableTypes(name='Mel')))
    db.session.commit()
db.session.add_all((
    Fermentables(
        name='Malte Pilsen',
        desc='Malte Extra Pilsen usada pelas principais cervejarias da Mundo. \
Possui alto poder diastático o que resulta em um tempo de sacarificação menor.',
        ppg='35',
        color='2,8',
        fermentable_producers='Agrária',
        fermentable_types='Malte de cevada')))
    db.session.commit()
```

---

Erro:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/home/carlos/code/env-python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
>     return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
>   File "/home/carlos/code/env-python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
>     response = self.handle_exception(e)
>   File "/home/carlos/code/env-python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
>     reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
>   File "/home/carlos/code/env-python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
>     raise value
>   File "/home/carlos/code/env-python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
>     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
>   File "/home/carlos/code/env-python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1808, in full_dispatch_request
>     self.try_trigger_before_first_request_functions()
>   File "/home/carlos/code/env-python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1855, in try_trigger_before_first_request_functions
>     func()
>   File "/home/carlos/code/brewblog/__init__.py", line 46, in create_admin_user
>     populate_fermentable()
>   File "/home/carlos/code/brewblog/utils.py", line 49, in populate_fermentable
>     fermentable_types_id='1')
>   File "/home/carlos/code/env-python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 153, in do
>     return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
>   File "/home/carlos/code/env-python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1784, in add_all
>     for instance in instances:
> TypeError: 'Fermentables' object is not iterable
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema da seguinte forma
Popular o banco de dados:

```
malte_cevada = FermentableTypes(name='Malte de cevada')
malte_trigo = FermentableTypes(name='Malte de trigo')
db.session.add_all((malte_cevada, malte_trigo))

agraria = FermentableProducers(name='Agrária')
cargil = FermentableProducers(name='Cargil')
db.session.add_all((agraria, cargil))

db.session.add_all((
    Fermentables(
        name='Malte Pilsen',
        desc='Malte Extra Pilsen usada pelas principais cervejarias da Mundo. Possui alto poder diastático o que resulta em um tempo de sacarificação menor.',
        ppg='35',
        color='2.8',
        fermentable_producers=cargil,
        fermentable_types=malte_cevada),
    Fermentables(
        name='Malte Pilsen',
        desc='Malte Extra Pilsen usada pelas principais cervejarias da Mundo. Possui alto poder diastático o que resulta em um tempo de sacarificação menor.',
        ppg='35',
        color='2.8',
        fermentable_producers=agraria,
        fermentable_types=malte_cevada),
))
db.session.commit()
```

Dessa forma funciona, apesar de não ficar da forma que eu queria, com cada parte dividida em uma função.

Comment: Perceba que agora você tem uma tupla com dois elementos na chamada ao `add_all` - o que eu escrevi na minha resposta está correto. Talvez você tenha tido algum outro erro ao tentar simplesmente escrever `.add` em vez de `.add_all` - mas  o "object is not iterable"  é por que você não estava passando uma tupla.

Answer (score 0):

Se você vai adicionar só um objeto no banco, use `db.session.add`, o método `add_all` é para um objeto iterável - no seu caso você deve ter copiado o código de algum lugar que adicionava uma tupla de objetos - eles estariam no menor nível de parênteses, separados por ",".

Em Python, objetos separados por "," são uma tupla - um objeto iterável - ela pode ou não estar entre parenteses - ex.  `(2, 5)`. Mas um único objeto entre parênteses é só o valor de uma expressão - os parêneteses são então descartados - no seu caso tem um nível parenteses sobrando dentro da chamada à `add_all`:  `add_all((Fermentables(...)))` - se quiser uma tupla com um único elemento (caso em que o `add_all` funcionaria), tem que ter uma vírgula dentro do parêneteses - é a forma oficial de se indicar tuplas de um único elemento: `add_all((Fermentables(...),))`. Mas-  reiterando o que eu disse lá em cima - você não precisa da tupla, nem do par extra de parenteses, nem chamar o `add_all` para inserir um único objeto no banco.

Comment: Não é somente isso, pois testei das 2 formas que você propos e não funcionou, mas obrigado

Comment: _esse_ erro é por isso - está bem visível no código acima.